# How to pass value from Carousel image in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React JS and trying to create a linkable carousel image using nuka-carousel. I've set up a data file to grab the images and the data for the links etc in the example below;

```
const RollList = [
  {
    headline: "Something Here 1",
    paragraph: "Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.",
    img_src: "http://placehold.it/755x435/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
    link: "/about",
    id: "roll-1"
    },
];
export default RollList;
```

The images load fine into the carousel, but I'm struggling to get the value of the link address from the function. I know it's available in the `props` as I can see it in the react dev tools plugin.

```
var React = require('react');
import RollList from '../../data/roll';
var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
const MonCarousel = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Carousel.ControllerMixin],

handleLink(event) {
    let linkName= event.target.value;
    console.log(linkName);
    // let path = `${linkName}`;
    // browserHistory.push(path);
},

render() {
    let moncarousel = RollList.map((roll) => {
        return (
            <img src={ roll.img_src } key={roll.id} onClick={this.handleLink} value={roll.link} onLoad={() => {window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));}}/>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <section class='carousel-section'>
                <div class='container'>
                    <div className="featured-row">
                        <div className="carousel-block">
                            <h4>Featured</h4>
                            <div className="carousel-shadow">
                                <Carousel speed={1200} autoplayInterval={7999} autoplay={true} wrapAround={true}>
                                    { moncarousel }
                                </Carousel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="carousel-side">
                            <div className="btn yel-btn">
                                Get in touch with us
                            </div>
                            <small>something here</small>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <div className="btn yel-btn">
                                Get in touch with us
                            </div>
                            <small>something here</small>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur sequi, minus molestiae perspiciatis, debitis adipisci eaque in recusandae voluptatum! Reiciendis enim vero expedita eaque placeat eligendi tempore minus consequuntur sequi.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
});
module.exports = MonCarousel;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with it? When the onClick event occurs, you want to link to the image src and open a new window with this? If so, the function looks okay, what does `console.log(event.target.value);` return? Undefined? If so, check what `roll.link` is returning. We need to find out where the point of failure is first,

Comment: @Dandy Thanks for the reply I get undefined when I log that via console.log(event.target.value);
but if i run console.log(event.target); I get:
<img src="http://placehold.it/755x435/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1" value="/about">

Comment: Forgot to say what I'm trying to do... I'm trying to use the `onClick` function to push the images associated value(`roll.link` url) into browserHistory. This is currently commented out in the above code until I can realise the value from the carousel image.

Comment: Try putting the `onClick()` last in the html element?

Comment: Although I did't really understand that logic I gave it a try without any joy